# Manage category is not saving

Tags: magento

i have a problem with the manage categories. When i tries to change the already created category "Name" then it cant changes and not saved into the database and gives me the below error in the console.
`"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.test.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/save/key/9487ff918e8f40544635df5359718b53/id/41/?isAjax=true"`
 But, when i create the new category then it is saved and does not created the above error. The Problem is arise  when i edit the old categories already created.
when i have seen in the console POST?Ajax=true the response gives as belowin the form of javascript 
`parent.updateContent("http://www.test.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/id/41/key/f437a3f3555a03e0f9f7750af5b4fb6c/", {}, true);`
It returns the null value as response.

Please, help me.....

Answer (score 0):

It might be your mod_security causing the 403 errors.

Try adding the following at the top of your .htaccess file in your Magento root directory:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

If that doesn't work, it would be easier to determine the exact cause my examining your apache error logs.  The logs will give you more insight into why you are receiving 403 errors.